# Modelling a censored outcome (tobit) with correlated data (random effect) in R

Tags: r, random-effects-model, censoring, clustered-standard-errors, tobit-regression

I have a continuous outcome that I need to assume is right-censored, so I'm looking for a way to fit a tobit regression model, however, my data are from family pedigrees so I also have to account for non-independence of my observations in some way (say with a random effects term). Can anyone think of a way to achieve this in R?